# Server Side validation doesnt seems to work in SpringBoot 2.3.1.RELEASE

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, validation

I have a POJO class and its API method. I want to validate user field input but it doesnt seems to work. I have used @Size() annotation in my POJO class but it is not working. Below is snippet of my logic structure.

**POJO Class**

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long addressId;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=10, max=100, message="Please enter between {min}-{max} characters")
    private String addressLine;
```

**API Class method**

```
@PostMapping(value="/add", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String addAddress( @RequestBody @Valid Address address, BindingResult result)
    {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return ErrorUtils.customErrors(result.getAllErrors());
        } else {
            return addressService.addAddress(address);
        }
    }
```

and i am creating JSON request for **addAddress (/add) method** and prompting the error in UI form. My JSON response handler is in jquery validator like below..

```
function saveRequestedData(frm, data, type) {
    $.ajax({
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type:frm.attr("method"),
        url:frm.attr("action"),
        dataType:'json',
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        success:function(data) {
            if(data.status == "success") {
            alert(data.message);
            toastr.success(data.message, data.title, {
                closeButton:true
            });
            fetchList(type);
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.message, data.title, {
                    allowHtml:true,
                    closeButton:true
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It seems only @NotNull seems to work not @Size and @Valid annotation. 
**As per Spring Boot Release notes**, Starting from version 2.3.0.RELEASE Spring Boot Web and WebFlux starters no longer depend on the validation starter, so i have added spring-boot-starter-validation in my pom.xml manually. 
But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you added @Validated at class level?

Comment: @SSK i did not, as i have already mentioned ```@Valid```  in API class method. But i tried your suggestion too by using ```@Validation``` in my controller class level. But it did not work.

Comment: it's a `@Validated` from `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;`

Comment: @SSK used the  ```@validated``` but it did not work like this --> ```@Controller
@RequestMapping("add")
@Validated
public class AddressController { ```

Comment: You need to use it on the class level. Adding the code as an answer for your reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code as a reference.

```
@Validated
@RestController
public AddressController{

@Autowired
private AddressService addressService;

@PostMapping(value="/add", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String addAddress( @RequestBody @Valid Address address, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return ErrorUtils.customErrors(result.getAllErrors());
        } else {
            return addressService.addAddress(address);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your responses. I got it working with the same code. And i did not use ```@Validated```. Instead i debugged the application and while debugging i found the logic was right but i was not providing the complete & correct user input length to enable error messages from spring framework.

Comment: Good to know that you have found the root cause. Keep it up.